# In what fields does $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=0$ imply that all the $x_i$'s are 0?

Tags: field-theory

And more specifically, are there any such fields which are not isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$? Certainly this is not satisfied in fields of finite characteristic, and also not in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You want an ordered field $F$. One consequence of the ordering is that $x^2\ge 0$ for all $x\in F$ and $x^2=0$ only when $x=0$. Since the sum of positive (nonnegative) elements is again positive (nonnegative), this will finish your proof.

Comment: Thanks! And are there ordered fields which are not isomorphic to a subfield of R? And are there fields that satisfy that property but cannot be ordered?

Comment: I think the $p$-adics might satisfy this property but are not an ordered field.

Comment: Of course any ordered field must contain a subset isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. If we think of rational functions $f(x)/g(x)$ with $f(x),g(x)$ having coefficients in $\Bbb Q$, then this seems to be an example not contained in $\Bbb R$, but it's isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(e)\subset\Bbb R$ (evaluate the rational functions at $x=e$). But what if we take rational functions with coefficients in $\Bbb R$? That's a field in which your desired implication holds, and it is not isomorphic to a subfield of $\Bbb R$. (P.S. A (topologically) *complete* ordered field must be isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.)